# Can Git/SVC work for me/my company?

Tags: git

I've been coding websites for about 20 years now, and have always worked alone, and have had my own ways of doing version control which, while not perfect, were good enough for me such that I never dove into any formal kinds of SVC. At my day job for the past 8 years, I've just been doing live-editing (I know, I know) because it works and I was the only one touching the templates on the site (Ellington CMS on top of Django system). We're switching things up now and several people have started getting access to editing templates, and as we start working on the same files, I'm really pushing the idea of us switching to using some kind of source control. Though I'm the only one who even knows what it is, and I've never even used it first hand. And on top of that, as far as I know, the only way to test the changes to a template file that we work on is to save it live to the site and check it that way. If we try viewing them on our local machines, it will just show the template code. I'm sure it can be done, but we really have no idea where to start. And my boss is (somewhat justifiably) concerned that if a program that we don't understand has full access to the website, we may accidentally do something to bring the whole thing down. I figured if anyone would know how we should proceed, it would be someone here. :-) I probably left out important information in the description, so feel free to ask anything that would help you help me. :) Thanks!

Comment: It's like reading a novel!

Comment: Sorry about that! I really wasn't sure what background info to include.

Comment: You need source control, and, more importantly, a dev server.

Comment: IMO, this is too-broad and primarily opinion-based. Check our tag wikis for very good starting points: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info

Comment: Paragraph breaks would be nice.

Comment: This question is being closed, but regardless: A version control system is definitely something you and your whole company should invest time on. While I can understand that working alone on just a few files works as you always make sure that you don’t break things and test things correctly, the probability that you do something you rather shouldn’t have done is still very high. And without a VCS it’s difficult to go back (I’ve been there). Even alone, you can gain a lot from a VCS like Git, so I’d suggest you to learn it for your own and then explain it to your coworkers.

Comment: Well, I'm starting to learn it, though everything I've learned is great for static sites that can run on my own computer, but nothing that tells me how I'd test updates accessing our CMS without making the changes live.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed What has that question to do with if you should use GIT or not? I think you are confused about what version control does. But the answer is that every single serious developer uses it. Not using it as stupid and amateurish.

Answer (score 1):

You will need both version control (I prefer Git over SVN, but that's just subjetive) and a development server (so changes are submited to the production one after being tested). The later is more important, because it will prevent your site from crashing if anything goes horribly wrong (in most cases).

A tutorial on git:

[Git tutorial](http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial)

Free git repository hosting:

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org)